# Laravel-Excel 2, get the year and month from "date" in Carbon format

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpexcel, laravel-excel

In Laravel-Excel 2, I'm reading a file like this:

[image]

The code to read it is this:

```
$my_file ='some/path/to/my_file.xls';
$data = Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($my_file, function($reader) {})->get()->toArray();
```

This it the output for `dd($data[0]);`, considering that `data`is an array:

[image]

I need to get the year (2005) and month (11) from "date". "date" is inside "fecha" and it is in Carbon format. How can I get it? I've been having a lot of problems reading that array-object thing. I thought that `$data[0]["fecha"]->date` would do the trick but, instead of that it works with:

```
$data[0]["fecha"].["date"]
```

But I'm having some errors in some versions of php with "Array to string conversion", but in my php it doesn't show the error, **so how should I get that year and month?** I don't get it.

This is the output of `print_r($data[0]);die();`:

```
Array (
    [fecha] => Carbon\Carbon Object (
        [date] => 2005-11-01 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/Santiago 
    ) 
    [hora] => 
    [bloquefr] => N 
    [dia] => 1 
    [activo_defecto] => 118.209 
    [reactivo_defecto] => 0 
    [empresa] => Luz Osorno 
    [barra_internal_name] => La Union 13.8 
    [barra_cen_name] => La Union 13.8 
    [barra_cne_name] => L.UNION_______013 
    [barra_cen_name_2] => La Union 1 023 
    [tipo_barra] => SPD 
)
```

EDIT: the output of `print_r($data[0]["fecha"].["date"]);die();` is

```
2005-11-01 00:00:00Array
```

I don't know what it means that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$data[0]["fecha"]->formatLocalized('Y');   // 2005
$data[0]["fecha"]->formatLocalized('m');   // 11
```

EDIT: the output of print_r($data[0]["fecha"].["date"]);die(); is

```
2005-11-01 00:00:00Array
```

because you are concatenating $data[0]["fecha"] and ["date"] with the operator '.' and printing it. Internally, is interpreted as:

```
$data[0]["fecha"]->toString.["date"]->toString
```

Comment: With `$data = Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($my_file, function($reader) {})->get()->toArray();
            print_r($data[0]["fecha"].["date"]->formatLocalized('%Y'));die();` I get: message: "Call to a member function formatLocalized() on array"

Comment: Yey, there I get `2005`. I was writing another problem but... it will not necesary, I solved with this. The whole problem with the code and version was the use of [][].[]  yes! thanks buddy, love you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call directly from Carbon object:

```
$str = $data[0]["fecha"]->format('Y m');
```